# selectively upgrade module in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am changing my one of the module's version to upgrade via "composer update" but when I run that command it keep installing and upgrading few other modules also. Is there anyway I can upgrade only selected module for which i have changed the version in "package.json"?

Answer (score 0):

Composer is a package manager and a *dependency manager*.

Without seeing your package.json file, I would bet that the module you are upgrading also has dependencies that also require upgrading. There is one thing you can dry though...

Tell composer to only update first degree dependencies.

```
php composer.phar --root-reqs --dry-run update
```

If that does not work, please update your question with the contents of package.json along with the module version that you're trying to upgrade from / to.